# Как открыть перископ (Periscope) из своего приложения?

Tags: android

Как открыть перископ (Periscope) или любое другое приложение из своего приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ (провека интента на null):

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```

Вариант 2: Если приложение не найденно отправляем в маркет искать его:

```
public void startNewActivity(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);


       if (intent == null) {
            // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно воспользоваться неявными интентами (implicit intents). Ознакомьтесь с этим: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html?hl=ru
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html